# Iterate through nested JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How do I parse through JSON with unknown variables?  I know "Europe" will always exist, but the city names (e.g. Germany, ...etc) will always be variable.  I am trying to extract the city and hostname from each entry.

```
{
  "Europe": {
    "Germany": [
      {
        "hostname": "host1"
      }
    ],
    "Poland": [
      {
        "hostname": "host2"
      }
    ],
    "Denmark": [
      {
        "hostname": "host3"
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Looks poor json format to me. Ideally, every value should have a valid key for traversing purpose.

Comment: You can try to convert it to a python dictionary and iterate over it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Umesh can you give me an example as to what you mean?

Comment: @EthanB, See this   `"continent": "Europe": {
    "country": "Germany": [
      {
        "hostname": "host1"
      }
    ],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through `countries['Europe'].items()`:

```
countries = {"Europe":
             {"Germany": [{"hostname": "host1"}],
              "Poland": [{"hostname": "host2"}],
              "Denmark": [{"hostname": "host3"}]}
             }    


for k, v in countries["Europe"].items():
    print(k, v[0]['hostname'])

Germany host1
Poland host2
Denmark host3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `json` to load as dictionary:

```
import json
contries = """
{
  "Europe": {
    "Germany": [
      {
        "hostname": "host1"
      }
    ],
    "Poland": [
      {
        "hostname": "host2"
      }
    ],
    "Denmark": [
      {
        "hostname": "host3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
"""
country_host = json.loads(contries)
for k,v in country_host['Europe'].items():
    print(k,v[0]['hostname'])
```

this will print out countries and its host:

```
Denmark host3
Germany host1
Poland host2
```

Comment: Note: OP is asking in Py3, so the output would be quite different from what you gave (not tupled, not wrapped in quotes or prefixed with `u`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library like `jsonpath-rw` and do the following (please check the [docs](http://jsonpath-rw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)):

```
from jsonpath_rw import jsonpath, parse
countries = {"Europe":
         {"Germany": [{"hostname": "host1"}],
          "Poland": [{"hostname": "host2"}],
          "Denmark": [{"hostname": "host3"}]}
         }
# To extract the country and hostname  
for country in parse('$.Europe.*').find(countries):
    for city in parse('$..hostname').find(country.value):
        print ('{}: {}'.format(country.path, city.value))
# Germany: host1
# Poland: host2
# Denmark: host3
```